# SharePoint 2010 SDK

Tags: 2010, sdk

Anyone know where I can download the SharePoint 2010 SDK. I'm particularly after the SharePoint 2010 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll. Looks like Microsoft have removed downloads for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 Client object model SDK only has 2 dlls , it deos not have support for search. To access search functionality of SP 2010 from client application you have to rely on search.asmx service.

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

You can download it from here..
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll is supported only from SP 2013

you can download that SP2013 version from below.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePoint.Client.Search/